# Hebrews 2:18, was suffering necessary for Jesus to be able helping the tempted?

Tags: hebrews, new-testament

Hebrews 2:18 (DRB):

> For in that, wherein he himself hath suffered and been tempted, he is able to succour them also that are tempted.

The question is so simple:

Was suffering necessary for Jesus to be able helping the tempted?

In other words, If Jesus doesn't suffer pain, He would be less able to save them who are tempted?

In other words, was suffering necessary for Jesus to accomplish his ability as a minister?

In other words, did suffering pain and death of Jesus have another aim/aims beside redemptive role?

I hope my words are clear.

Comment: @MohamedSalim I am a Sufi (Mystic), a Traditionalist, a Perennial  Philosopher. For me, all considerable Holy Books carry the word of God. The Vedas, The Bible, The Holy Quran, are all accepted for me. All of them carry the word of God.

Answer (score 2):

Suffering is not a qualification for the redeemer to redeem us from sin or even to help us in temptation.

He came to earth to live a righteousness life. He did this despite the troubles he came across.

He raised the bar and showed how a man can live righteously.

To set an example 
He prayed everyday to Heavenly Father 
He read scriptures to teach Jews
He was tempted by Satan to show that He is vulnerable (and also to show His defensive guard)

In this way He went through hardship and troubles.

Answer (score 2):

In Heb 2:18, the trials and temptations of Jesus had a two-fold purpose:

1. To provide a perfect example of endurance to us who are charged with imitating Christ, 16:33, 1 Cor 7:28, 2 Tim 1:4, Heb 13:12, 13, 1 Peter 2:21, Eph 5:1
2. To demonstrate that Jesus was truly human and thus really does understand us from first hand experience.  This helps us trust Him and learn from Him.  Matt 11:29, Heb 4:14-16.
3. The idea in Heb 2:18 and its word πειρασθείς (peirastheis) from the root word πειράζω (peirazó) is a "trial" in order to demonstrate something's integrity.  Jesus endured far greater tests of character than any human ever did or ever will, but never sinned, Heb 4:15.

Thus, Jesus is ideally suited to being our Savior and Redeemer.  Barnes comes to a similar conclusion:

> Being tempted - Or, being "tried." The Greek word used here is more
>   general in its meaning than the English word "tempted." It means to
>   "put to the proof;" to try the nature or character of; and this may be
>   done either:
>
> (1) by subjecting a person to "afflictions" or "sufferings" that his
>   true character may be tried - that it may be seen whether he has
>   sincere piety and love to God; or.
>
> (2) by allowing one to fall into "temptation," properly so called -
>   where some strong inducement to evil is presented to the mind, and
>   where it becomes thus a "trial" of virtue.
>
> The Saviour was subjected to both these in as severe a form as was
>   ever presented to people. His sufferings surpassed all others; and the
>   temptations of Satan (see Matthew 4) were presented in the most
>   alluring form in which he could exhibit them. Being "proved" or
>   "tried" in both these respects, he showed that he had a strength of
>   virtue which could bear all that could ever occur to seduce him from
>   attachment to God; and at the same time to make him a perfect model
>   for those who should be tried in the same manner.
>
> He is able to succour ... - This does not mean that he would not have
>   had "power" to assist others if he had not gone through these
>   sufferings, but that he is now qualified to sympathize with them from
>   the fact that he has endured like trials.
>
> "He knows what sore temptations mean,
>
> For he has felt the same."